# change "date.struct" to date in Grails

Tags: grails

I have `<g:datePicker>` in my view in **Grails2.5.1** application, the returned value for this filed in the controller is `date.struct` , how i could change this value to actual date .
here is my view :

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: empRefInstance, field: 'endDate', 'error')} ">
<label for="endDate">
    <g:message code="empRef.endDate.label" default="End Date" />

</label>
<g:datePicker name="endDate" relativeYears="[-90..0]" precision="day"  value="${empRefInstance?.endDate}" default="none" noSelection="['null':'Present']" />
```

here is how i access it in the controller:

```
println "date : " +params.endDate"
```

Comment: I have never seen that before. How are you using g:datePicker? Please add the actual code to your question. And also add how you're accessing it within the controller method.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa , i edited the original post

Comment: any ideas for that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a string with the date.struct and then use simpledateformat like in http://grails.asia/converting-java-string-to-date

```
    String Date = endDate_year+"/"+endDate_month+"/"+endDate_day
    SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date dt = sdformat.parse(date);
    println(dt)
```

Answer (score -1):

What's happening is the date from the [datePicker](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/0b1d6a6d02f2217643a69e8314f76078dacbce32/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy) is actually fractured into separate params keys. For instance, you'll have keys such as `params.endDate_month`, `params.endDate_day`, `params.endDate_year`. So you can piece it back together into a date like this:

```
def endDate = new Calendar().with {
    set(params.endDate_year, params.endDate_month, params.endDate_day, params.endDate_hour, params.endDate_minute, 0)
    getTime() // Returns a Date instance.
}
```